# How to generate random number only once every seconds in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random, react-native

The question is very simply yet the solution is quite confusing.

My current implementation is that I'm generating random number between 50 to 100 and save it using **`this.setState({...})`** Which I then call it in my render method.

But the gotcha is that the random method in itself generates random number multiple times. This is because every time the **`this.setState({...})`** is called, the render method renders few times and during this rendering, the random number changes, which is not what I want.

```js
export default class exampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      randomNumber: 0
    };
  }

  generateRandomNumber = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

  myview = () => {
    const { randomNumber } = this.state;

    setInterval(() => this.setState({randomNumber: generateRandomNumber(50, 100)}), 20000);

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{randomNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        {this.myview()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

How can i ensure that the random number doesnt change multiple times after setState() is called?

Comment: A raw solution: you might try this: `this.setState(() => {return {randomNumber: generateRandomNumber(50, 100)}; })`

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to assign the randomly generated number to state? Can you assign it to `this.randomNumber` or something? It's still available within the react class but just wont cause a re-render

Something like this:

```
export default class exampleComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.randomNumber = 0

    this.generateRandomNumber = this.generateRandomNumber.bind(this)

  }

  newRandomNumber(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
  }

  generateRandomNumber(){
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.randomNumber = this.newRandomNumber(1, 1000)
    }, 20000)
  }



  myview = () => {

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.randomNumber}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        {this.myview()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Attempt 2:

I have used javascript to get the element and update the innerHtml without re-rendering the whole component:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.randomNumber = 0

    this.generateRandomNumber = this.generateRandomNumber.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.generateRandomNumber() // calls it the first time and the setInterval will keep running
  }

  newRandomNumber(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
  }

  generateRandomNumber(){
    setInterval(() => {
      document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = this.newRandomNumber(1, 1000)
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div id="randomNumber"></div>

      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Comment: If there is a way of getting the random number without using the setstate then by all means I'll go with that

Comment: I see what your doing. Although you are partially correct, one issue is that the `this.randomNumber` is doesnt return the new value after every few seconds. It only returns from the first call made in constructor

Comment: @Katie yes you were correct. I have given you a second example which I have tested. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Hmm, I dont think I can mess with inner html in react native

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise it was react-native. Is there not an equivalent for updating text value?

Comment: Not sure tbh. There should be a way for direct manipulation in react native

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use   setInterval() this method will keep on giving you random numbers which is not what you want from what i understood?

Just use

```
setTimeout(function() {
      //your code to be executed after x seconds
    }, delayInMilliseconds);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Comp extends React.Component {
state = {
      randomNumber: 0
 }

 generateRandomNumber = (min, max) => { 
    const random = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min)
    console.log("random ", random)
    this.setState({
      randomNumber: random
    })
   }

  render() {
    setTimeout(this.generateRandomNumber.bind(this, 50, 100),1000)
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.randomNumber}
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

codepen : [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rdxVyr)